# Executing Fabric Script through JAVA

Tags: java, runtime, fabric

I have this simple fab script and I want to execute this through JAVA:

```
    from __future__ import with_statement
    from fabric.api import *
    from fabric.contrib.console import confirm
    env.hosts = ['localhost']

    def updatefile():
     with shell_env(TERM='vt100'):
    with cd('/Users/'):
    run("pwd")
    run("ls -l")

    def execute():
      updatefile()
```

When I execute this script from command line it works : fab -f test.py executes but I want to execute via java.  Tried with ..

```
public class ExecuteScript {

@Test
public void testExecuteScript() throws NumberFormatException, IOException{

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("fab -f src/test/resources/scripts/test.py execute");
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(output.toString());
}
}
```

It doesn't work.. looked at the documentation for java examples in http://fabric8.io/gitbook/quickstarts.html the links are broken.

Answer (score 0):

Environment, make sure you're using your environment. I would suggest you use `virtualenv`, looks something like this:

1. `virtualenv .env` (dont do this in your src folder, if anything it should be one directory down, and also please don't check this into your source control)
2. `source .env/bin/activate`

then install your dependencies:

1. `pip install fabric`
2. ?? what ever else you need.

then this is the important part:

`./.env/bin/fab -f src/test/resources/scripts/test.py execute`